# How can I access a variable that is outside of my foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop inside of a while loop. I'm using a standard setup as far as using $i and $i++ to iterate. This is my code (shortened):

```
// Get a database object
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$month = date('n');
$day = date('j');
$year = date('Y');

$currentDay = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;
//echo $currentDay;

// create the list of accessories
$i = 0;
while($i < 20) {

    $yesterday = strtotime ( "-$i days" , strtotime ( $currentDay ) ) ;
    $yesterday = date ( 'n/j/Y' , $yesterday );

    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__cappz_homelinks WHERE date='{$yesterday}' ORDER BY id ASC";
    // Executes the current SQL query string.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    // returns the array of database objects
    $list = $db->loadObjectList();

    if($list[0]->date) {//if there's a date
        echo '<h2>';
        echo $yesterday;
        echo '</h2>';

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($list as $item) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->headline.$i.'</a>';
            echo '</li>';
            $i++;
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get $i (inside the foreach loop) to increment when the foreach loop runs, but my PHP script just times out. When I move $i++ outside of the foreach, it works fine...but then of course that's not what I need.

*EDIT* I just posted the full code. It is connecting using the Joomla database object.

Comment: Are you sure `$list` has atleast 20 elements?

Comment: If there aren't enough entries in list[0] with a date, then $i will never reach 20 in the foreach loop, and it's never incremented outside of that if test, so it will become a permanent loop (depending on what your database code does)

Comment: Yup. When I move $i++ outside of the foreach, but still inside the while loop, works fine.

Comment: Your `if()` statement body is ignored. Possibly.

Comment: This is very fragile code. If `$list[0]->date` evaluates to `false` or `$list` has less than 20 entries, `$i` is never incremented and will never be >= 20.

Comment: @Micah that's because if you move it out of the foreach it will _definitely_ increment atleast once per iteration of while.

Comment: As @Dogbert said, you might now have 20 elements on the $list, that's why it keep looping..

Comment: It should work, perhaps you should post all your code? If you remove $i++ you will get never ending loop

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm still wondering why $list[0]->date not being true would kill the code. Shouldn't it just skip ahead to the next loop? Sorry for the lack of knowledge. *And I do have more than 30 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would limit your listings to just 20 items using SQL LIMIT instead of a loop or counter.

```
// Get a database object
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$month = date('n');
$day = date('j');
$year = date('Y');

$currentDay = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;
//echo $currentDay;

// create the list of accessories

$yesterday = strtotime ( "-$i days" , strtotime ( $currentDay ) ) ;
$yesterday = date ( 'n/j/Y' , $yesterday );

$query = "SELECT * FROM #__cappz_homelinks WHERE date='{$yesterday}' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20";
// Executes the current SQL query string.
$db->setQuery($query);
// returns the array of database objects
$list = $db->loadObjectList();

if(count($list)>0 && $list[0]->date/*not sure if this is needed*/) {//if there's a date
        echo '<h2>';
        echo $yesterday;
        echo '</h2>';

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($list as $item) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->headline.$i.'</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks...it worked! Can you tell me why this is bad code design? I reposted the full code up top...

Comment: @Micah You were re-opening the connection to the database up to 20 times to retrieve 20 items. I thought possibly you were using the $i variable to incremement and select a different set of data, but you were just mistaken. I modified the code to use SQL LIMIT instead of a PHP counter. Just as easily you could add "$i++; if($i>20) exit;" to the bottom of the inside of the foreach loop and get the same results.